# Как реализовать многопоточный брут на c#?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

У меня есть база логинов, паролей, портов и ip адресов. Суть в том, что нужно реализовать отдельный перебор для каждого ip адреса в потоках.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int threads = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i <= threads; i++)
        {
            string[] ips = File.ReadAllLines(IpsFile);
            string[] ports = File.ReadAllLines(PortsFile);
            string[] logins = File.ReadAllLines(LoginFile);
            string[] passwords = File.ReadAllLines(PasswordFile);

            foreach (string ip in ips)
            {
                foreach (string port in ports)
                {
                    foreach (string login in logins)
                    {
                        foreach (string password in passwords)
                        {
                            Brute brute = new Brute(ip, int.Parse(port), login, password);
                            Thread myThread = new Thread(brute.BruteForce)
                            {
                                Name = "Thread #" + i
                            };
                            myThread.Start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Если вы хакер и хотите что-нибудь взломать, почему вы не поступаете как хакер и не найдёте необычное решение самостоятельно?

Comment: Я уже написал подобный брутфорс на c++, но для Linux. Мне нужна кроссплатформенность.

Comment: @VladD да ну ладно, я в школе, когда программировать начинал, тоже брутфорсеры писал :). Из чисто научного интереса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, что хакер ищет решения на данном ресурсе. Разве хацкер ищет легкие пути ?
Воспользуйся классом `Task` и его методом `.WaitAll()`. Получишь многопоточный брут.

```
        List<string> IPs = GetIPs();           
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string IP in IPs)
        {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((IP)=>{/*тут должна быть логика брута на конкретный IP адрес*/}, tasks.Count));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не очень понял, куда это нужно добавить. И можете не назвать меня "хакером". Я пишу это просто из-за интереса к этой теме.

Comment: Замените комментарий на три вложенных foreach из вопроса. При этом оттуда нужно убрать все, что касается Threads.

Comment: Вот, что у меня вышло [ссылка](https://snag.gy/7x3Y8b.jpg)

Comment: уберите string из StartNew. Ну и осталось добавить логику брутфорса во внутренний foreach.

Comment: Теперь вот такая проблема. [Скриншот](https://snag.gy/KDHhGk.jpg)

Comment: @frago `tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>`